# How do I remap a URL?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, url-rewriting

I need to move an old legacy web service to a new location. It will be under a virtual directory now rather than it's own website in IIS. Unfortunately I can't change the config settings for a client that is using the service, so is there a way to map the URL from the old address to a different site in a virtual directory?

Eg.

http://oldservice.oursite.com/aservice.asmx

moves to

http://newsubdomain.oursite.com/oldservice/aservice.asmx

I then want http://oldservice.oursite.com/ to map to http://newsubdomain.oursite.com/oldservice/

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a redirect on the old virutal directory in IIS to the new location.

Open IIS, click on Home Directory tab, then select "redirection to a url"